# Interceptors/Filters in Spray

Tags: scala, spray

I'm busy migrating one of our Spring/Groovy applications to Spray/Scala. I'm fairly new to Spray, so forgive me if this is a beginner question.

The objective is to emulate our logging Interceptor, which logs various data for every request/response.  There is quite a lot of logic that goes on in this part of the code, so its not a simple log line. Also, I'd like to wrap ALL requests that come in with this logic.

Existing Groovy/Spring Interceptor:

```
boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler {
  //do some logging logic
}


void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
  //do some more logging logic
}
```

My Scala actor looks like this

```
class BootServiceActor extends Actor with ViewingController with LazyLogging with ViewingWire {

def actorRefFactory = context

implicit val ctx = context.dispatcher

def receive = runRoute(route)(exceptionHandler, RejectionHandler.Default, context,
  RoutingSettings.default, LoggingContext.fromActorRefFactory)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the big selling points of Spray/Scala is that you can avoid "magic", invisible things like interceptors. You achieve the same things by using types and/or directives, but everything you're doing becomes visible in the code and refactor-safe thanks to the type system. E.g. you could use a scalaz `Writer` to accumulate log messages associated with a particular request, and then define a "meta-marshaller" that provided `Marshaller[Writer[MyLogStructure, A]]` for any `A` which had an existing marshaller, and wrote all the logs for that particular request in the correct structure. I'm happy to go into more detail about this approach if you like.

The "pre-handle" part is probably best handled by a simple `Directive`; since Spray is reactive and async there's not really a concept of paired "before and after" handling. Rather, you do something to the request and hand it off to the next processing step, that will eventually send a response. If you need to pass some "context" through from the pre-handle to the post-handle, again that's probably best done with a "context type" (I'm trying to avoid saying the scary m-word) like `State`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm attempting to do the Directive approach.  There is a DubuggingDirective that comes with Spray that outputs the request/response, and I'm attempting to copy/paste repurpose that code.  Do you have any info around passing the "context type"/State around?  Generally I could use a threadlocal/request object, but I'm not certain that is possible with Spray?

Comment: Threadlocal won't work, the response might be sent by a different thread. You can do as that debugging directive does, `mapRequestContext` and within that do `withRouteResponseMapped`, so the data is actually in a closure that gets called when the response eventually happened, but in that case you won't have access within the routes. If you want access to it inside you can pass it around explicitly (i.e. provide it from your directive); you could declare it as implicit and pass it to functions as an implicit parameter to make it easier to work with.

Comment: But what I was alluding to is the functional way of threading a mutable state through a computation, the [scalaz state monad](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html). You can compose together computations that work with a state using `for`/`yield`, and the other scalaz tools (e.g. `traverse`) operate nicely on them, and then you make your directive accept a `State[MyInfo, Route]` or some such. But that's maybe overkill for a simple case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution I implemented based on lmm's input**

I ended up making a custom Directive, something along these lines:

```
trait LoggingDirectives {

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[LoggingDirective])

  import spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives._

  def logResponseInfo(user : String): Directive0 =
    mapRouteResponse { response ⇒
      //...
      logger.info("RESPONSE >> "+user+":"+response)
      response
    }

  def logRequestInfo: Directive0 =
    mapRequest { request ⇒
      //...
      logger.info("REQUEST << " + request);
      request
    }
}
```

I then wrapped it around my route:

```
val route = logRequestInfo {
  accountAuthenicationValidator { profileId:String =>
    logResponseInfo(profileId) {
      controllerRoute(profileId)
    }
  }
}
```

where accountAuthenicationValidator is another custom directive, and controllerRoute is the core route that handles ALL paths and is a (String => Route)

Comment: Looks good. Note that if you want to apply a bunch of directives in the same place you can use `&` to combine the directives into one rather than needing `{}` at each level.